# How to find the total size of AWS S3 storage folder using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to find the total size of AWS S3 storage folder using lambda. The aim is to as I upload an object to S3 folder it will trigger lambda and lambda will get the metrics for that folder and send me SNS notification with the details. My is issue here is how to Lambda code and how to set up the lambda to do this action.

The CLI version of the wanted action and results are as following:

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://ahmedfarghaly/moe
```

The results required are as following:

```
2017-12-18 21:35:58    0 Bytes moe/
    2017-12-18 21:36:40    6.4 MiB moe/xmen.mp4

    Total Objects: 2
       Total Size: 6.4 MiB
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python boto3, use `list_objects` API. Details can be found [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects). It returns the size in bytes. Sample code:

```
import boto3
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=os.getenv('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'))
    response = client.list_objects(
        Bucket='ahmedfarghaly',
        Marker='moe'
    )
    for content in response['Contents']:
        size = content['Size'] / 1024
        print str(size) + " KB"
    return 'Completed'
```

Comment: so in order to send the results to through sns do I just add this part :    
import json
import boto3

message = {"foo": "bar"}
client = boto3.client('sns')
response = client.publish(
    TargetArn=arn,
    Message=json.dumps({'default': json.dumps(message)}),
    MessageStructure='json'
)

Comment: Yes. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you import Boto3 in your Lambda, the following one liner should give the size of the bucket in the default region. Otherwise, pass the region when calling boto3 client.

```
bucket_size = sum(obj['Size'] for obj in boto3.client('s3').list_objects(Bucket='ahmedfarghaly')['Contents'])
```